# Parse Eposodes with a Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse season and episode(s) information from at filename

In this filename there are two episodes:

```
Kampen.Om.Tungtvannet.S01E01E02.Retail.DKsubs.720p.HDTV.x264-RAPiDCOWS
```

And so far I have this Expression :

```
(?<season>\d{1,2})x(?<episode>\d{1,2})|S(?<season>\d{1,2})E(?<episode>\d{1,2})
```

But how do I change the expression so I get all episodes out of the filename?

If it makes any diffrence the regular Expression are to be used from c#

Comment: Can you have multiple seasons as well in same file name? Or just multiple episodes e.g. S01E01E02...E30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
S(?<season>\d{1,2})|(?<eposode>(?<=E)\d{1,2})
```

[Live](https://regex101.com/r/gY3iN8/1)